# How do I easily and cleanly update ruby 1.9 to the latest version on Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: ruby

Full disclosure. I do not use Ruby. I never have even looked into learning it as a language.

We use ruby at our company to power an integration between a couple of our tools. Due to a TLS update we have to update our ruby version from 1.9.2 to the newest version.

On this windows server 2008 r2 machine I have that version of ruby and need to update. The problem is this tool is in constant use. So I cannot reasonably take the server down for a whole day while I try to figure out what to do. Initial research shows that these older versions of ruby are problematic to update.

I have only a half dozen gems to worry about (and found a really good guide on updating those - I think).

Looking for a kind soul who is willing to help a lost soul.

Is this a case of needing to completely uninstall and if so does that mean uninstall my gems as well? Or can I just run an update via cmd?

Comment: Do you have a clone of this environment on which to test?

Comment: Odds are: you will have to update a number of gem dependencies (and/or their dependencies, etc. etc.).  And worse, many of those may have had breaking changes to their interfaces.  There's a good chance the integration will break.  Can you post the Gemfile at least?  Do you have to go to latest, or can you go to something newer that isn't all the way to 2.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly going to come down to your gem dependencies.

As for just the language, the odds of encountering anything that works with Ruby 1.9.3, but not Ruby 2.0+ will be highly unlikely. Plenty of features have been added, but on a whole, backwards compatibility has been maintained.

This is not necessarily the case with gems, as the dependencies and robustness of the code can vary wildly depending on the source. The only real way to answer anything with confidence is to check/compare dependencies of each gem you require with your target Ruby version. Typically increasing the Ruby version is less likely to "break" anything than lowering it obviously, but it is still a significantly plausible scenario you must be wary of and prepare against.

The only real way to do this without downtime is to clone or setup a new environment for testing, install the newer Ruby, install the required gems you have researched dependencies, and test to make sure everything runs/works as expected.

Unfortunately there is no "magic bullet" here that is going to solve this issue for you. Luckily, the vast majority of this does not require knowledge of Ruby syntax and coding, and if everything goes well, will require nothing more than installing Ruby, installing gems, and comparing versions. If you run into issues with specific gems, I am confident that there is a host of people here on SO that can help guide you through reconciling it.